# aapt error 138 processDebugResources

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, aapt

Ran in to this frustrating error today when building/making project, this seems to be since installing Android SDK 22.6 (have tried the 22.6.1 too) using build tools 19.0.1,19.0.2 and 19.0.3. The aapt error is causing R.java not to be generated.

I thought it was something project related as I have another project that builds ok. I've tried cleaning project/workspace, new workspace, reinstall Eclipse and Android SDK, then ported to Android studio gradle which is the error I've included below.

**Edit: I also reverted project to previous commit that worked**

Anyone ran in to this kind of thing? normally a clean works but not this time.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/scottab/dev/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/scottab/dev/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /Users/MyApp/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/MyApp/build/res/all/debug -A /Users/MyApp/build/assets/debug -m -J /Users/MyApp/build/source/r/debug -F /Users/MyApp/build/libs/MyApp-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.myapp.android --output-text-symbols /Users/MyApp/build/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    138
```

Comment: Have you changed any resources lately? AAPT crashes tend to be due to resources with missing references (e.g. a menu resource has a nonexistent @string reference)

Comment: I reviewed recent changes couldn't spot anything obvious, but reverted to several previous commits that compiled aok.

Comment: Double check not just menu references, but your namespace too. In particular, one easy way this happens is if you have app:showAsAction instead of android:showAsAction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a bug in AAPT, where it crashes when it sees a reference to a nonexistent resource. Unfortunately, it requires you to go through your resource files to try to spot the error, as it tends to not give you useful information.

This is written up in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61308 and if you look there you'll find examples of what other users have fixed to solve the crash.

Comment: Thank you for this, I deleted all the menu.xml files and commented where they were used and boom! I have R! adding them back one by one I found the problem file - although to look at it's fine. When I rolled back I obviously didn't roll back far enough.

Comment: Very useful answer  - in my case a simple spelling mistake   serch/search   <!-- Action Buttons 
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_serch"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        ></item>
    -->

Answer (score 19):

I'm a little late, but if you originally included appcompat in your project and later removed it, there's probably a stale reference in your menu xml.

Here's what menu looks like with appcompat

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

See the `app:showAsAction="never"`? That's what the issue was for me. Switching it back to `android:showAsAction="never"` fixed it for me.

Comment: This was my problem, the menu .xml was automatically generated by Android Studio

Comment: Android Studio had automatically generated a menu file for me. Even though I had selected the minSdk to be 14 (Android 4.0), it somehow had decided to still use AppCompat in some parts of the app. Replacing the `app` with `android` solved the issue.

Comment: This happened to me when I used AS->New->Blank Activity.  It added the menu.xml, updated build.gradle, and added an appcompat import.  All of these needed to be expunged for the cryptic fail in the gradle `:app:processDebugResources` task to go away.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what happened to me, this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I coded to get over the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:blogreader="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto "
    >

        <item  android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          blogreader:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

where in blogreader is the name of the application.

Reference: [Adding action buttons](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same problem, but no answer here, nor comment, helped me.

At the end there were 2 problems, probably one caused by the other...

1. My antivirus (Avast) detected "threat" from one SDK file... so probably my Android Studio thought there was no inclusion of AppCompat library in my "build.graddle" file and added a second one automatically. It looked like this:

   ```
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+" 
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+"
   ```

So I deleted one of them and i got R class back, but "appt" error was still there.

2. Aparently my dear Avast  took some exe's from SDK folder, so I started "SDK Manager". In the manager, the "SDK Compile Tools" I was using (2.1.1 I think) was unckecked (maybe failed at checksum comarison), so I re-installed it.

And VOILA!, It worked and now I'm happy.

Answer (score -3):

```
dexOptions {
    incremental false
    preDexLibraries = false
    jumboMode = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
}
```