# How can I view Android build Gradle tasks from Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I was dealing with this [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485209/aapt-error-138-processdebugresources) recently while learning my way around AS.

I could see that the error was occurring after running `aapt` during the `:app:processDebugResources` gradle task.

The Gradle window is available from View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle, where I can see a list of all of these tasks that are presumably found in the Android Build plugin.  Is there any way to view those tasks from AS?  Could I access the source code for the plugin somewhere?  The context menu presents no useful options, except `Open Gradle config` which is greyed out.

[image: Gradle console]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source for the android gradle plugin [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/8edc5752c4e21c67d66f48545b42f327fe229295/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle) (check it out in git).

The question you linked to says the bug is caused by a missing resource? Maybe run lint checks to find missing resources?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The bug is caused by lots of things apparently.  In my case, it was being caused by a couple of auto-generated things made by adding a new activity through the wizard, including one resource.