# how do i solve android studio 1.0.2 build error (error code 132)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded the android studio on ubuntu a few days back to start learning android application development, but I am stuck with this build error which I am not able to solve since past two days.

here is the **error**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/rohit/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /home/rohit/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar -M /home/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/TheTestProject/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/TheTestProject/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /home/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/TheTestProject/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /home/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/TheTestProject/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /home/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/TheTestProject/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.rohit.thetestproject -0 apk --output-text-symbols /home/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/TheTestProject/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    132
```

and here is the **build.gradle** file:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rohit.thetestproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

I tried to fix it by reading some solutions posted on similar questions but they did not work.

- Build -> Clean Project (didn't work)
- using build tool version 20 and target SDK version 20 (didn't work)
- tried to look for undefined string values (couldn't find)
- deleted menu_main.xml (didn't work)
- changed this **app:showAsAction="never"** to this **android:showAsAction="never"** (didn't work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [aapt error 138 processDebugResources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485209/aapt-error-138-processdebugresources)

Comment: can you suggest me something that I can do in order to fix it, because I cannot find anything more that I can do please

Comment: Hi Rohit, Is your code online anywhere ?

Comment: Here it is, https://www.dropbox.com/s/arb9npigln5hppt/app.zip?dl=0